# Center text in non-centered line

Tags: spacing, alignment

I need a line of text with three texts, aligned to the left, to the center and to the right respectively, so I tried to separate them with `\hfill`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\noindent foo\hfill foo\hfill foo

\noindent foobar foobar foobar foobar foobar foobar\hfill foo\hfill foo

\noindent\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

If the texts have the same length it works, but if they are different it doesn't. I understand that `\hfill` divides the empty space in the line in as many parts as the times the command is given and just places them where the command itself is given. That means that the center text is centered in the empty space between the left and the right ones, but I want it to be centered between the left and right margins.

To make it clearer, this is what I get:

[image]

And this is what I want:

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: Is it just for the first line?

Comment: Try `\rlap{left}\hfill center\hfill\llap{right}`.

Comment: @Bernard In the specific situation it is, but a "general" solution might be useful for other ones too. Thank you for your interest!

Comment: @JohnKormylo "center" and "right" are moved one line below. I looked around for a solution and I found that preceding `\rlap{left}` with `\leavevmode` it works as I need, but I can't rellay understand _why_ it works. May you give a reference to an explanation?

Comment: This construct is usually placed into an `\hbox to \textwidth`, so no `\leavevmode` needed.  I can't really find a reference.   The TeXbook showed examples of `\headline` using left-right  or centered, but not all three.  I discovered it independently many years ago.

Answer (score 2):

As far as i'm aware you can think of the pushing effects of `\hfill` as being identical to the pushing effects of compressed mechanical springs with infinite expandability. As long as I have internalized this analogy I encountered no situation where it was conceptually wrong.

The following figure is an attempt to illustrate this analogy schematically.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circledsteps}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{xsavebox}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, decorations.pathmorphing, tikzmark, calc}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\tikzset{
    inline/.style = {
        baseline, xshift=-2pt
    },
    inline insert/.style = {
        overlay, inline
    },
    my mark/.style = { 
        green!40!black, thick
    },
    spring/.style = {
        {|[width=1em]}-{|[width=1em]},
        semithick,
        orange!95!black,
        /pgf/decoration/name=coil,
        /pgf/decoration/aspect=-0.37,
        /pgf/decoration/post length=0.4mm,
        /pgf/decoration/pre length=0.7mm,
        /pgf/decoration/amplitude=1.5mm,
        /pgf/decoration/segment length=#1
    },
    force/.style = {
        to path = {
            decorate {([yshift=1.5mm]\tikztostart) -- ([yshift=1.5mm]\tikztotarget)}
        },
        execute at begin to = {
            \begin{scope}[
                overlay,
                <-,
                help lines, 
                draw=red!70!black,
                shorten <= -2mm,
                >=latex
            ]
                \draw ([yshift=4.5mm]\tikztostart)  -- ++ (#1,0);
                \draw ([yshift=4.5mm]\tikztotarget) -- ++(-#1,0);
            \end{scope}
        }
    }
}


\newcommand\Mybox[1]{%
    \adjustbox{
        padding*=0.2em 1em 0.2em 1em,
        frame,
        minipage=\linewidth,
        margin*=0em 1em 0em 0em,
        precode={\sffamily}{}
    }{\sffamily\normalsize%
        #1
    }
}

\xsavebox{spring}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[spring={0.9mm}, -, /pgf/decoration/post length=0.9mm, /pgf/decoration/pre length=1.5mm, 
        /pgf/decoration/aspect=-0.39,
        decorate] (0,0) -- (0.8,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand\Insert[1]{%
    \tikz[inline insert]{\draw[my mark, <-<, >=Latex] (0,0) -- (0,2.5em) node[rotate=50, anchor=south west, inner sep=0pt] {#1};}%
}

\newcommand\InlineSpring[1]{%
    \tikz{\draw[spring={#1}, force=0.3] (0,0) to (0.4,0)}%
}

\begin{document}
\small 
\Mybox{foobar foobar foobar foobar foobar foobar \Insert{\ttfamily \textbackslash hfill}foo \Insert{\ttfamily \textbackslash hfill}foo}\bigskip\bigskip

\Mybox{foobar foobar foobar foobar foobar foobar \Insert{\Circled{\xusebox{spring}}}foo \Insert{\Circled{\xusebox{spring}}}foo}

Imagine \texttt{\textbackslash hfill} directives as compressed springs being placed between boxes.\par\bigskip
\Mybox{foobar foobar foobar foobar foobar foobar\InlineSpring{0.35mm}foo\InlineSpring{0.35mm}foo}

The springs expand until the left and rightmost glyphs are pushed against the page margins.\par\bigskip
\Mybox{foobar foobar foobar foobar foobar foobar\tikzmark{1-start}\hfill\tikzmark{1-end}foo\tikzmark{2-start}\hfill\tikzmark{2-end}foo}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \foreach \i in {1,2} {
        \draw[spring={1.9mm}, force=0.17] (pic cs:\i-start) to (pic cs:\i-end);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As a mechanical engineer, I so want to use these sort of spring analogies, and they can indeed be helpful as mnemonic tools.  But they can also be...incomplete...in their explanatory value.  Consider this: `\begin{figure}[ht]\hfill\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}\hfill\end{figure}`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thank you for your comment. I'm aware of this case. If the right 'spring' has nothing to push towards the right margin it has basically no effect in a ragged left world where texts are read mainly from left to right. In a parrallel universe with a Knuth of arabic origin it's exactly the other way round i guess :)

Comment: Yes, the issue isn't so much that the spring mnemonic is wrong.  It is that Knuth & Lamport insert a lot a springs (and anchors) into (La)TeX hidden from the user's view, which can confound a simple explanation.  And that is before we even get into the notions of `fil`, `fill`, and `filll`.

Comment: @user1146332 That's not really an answer to the question, but very good explanation, and tikz work too!